# A comic or comics? (About one comic strip)

Tags: grammatical-number

Which grammatical number should be used when speaking about *one* comic strip consisting of *several* pictures?

I would use "comics" in both cases:

> This comics is very interesting (about one comic strip).
>
> These comics
>   are very interesting (about several comic strips).

Comment: This "comic (strip)" is very interesting. These "comic (-s/strips)" are very interesting.

Comment: And *Are you a fan of the comics?* has the approximate meaning, "Do you like to read that section of the newspaper?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This comics* is not grammatical. Because *comics* is plural, it has to read *these comics*.

But a *comic strip* is just that, a number of pictures/images strung together to tell a visual story.

*Comics* in the plural is understood to refer to a number of such strips/magazines or to comedians.

So the correct answers are:

> > This comic (or comic strip) is very interesting,

and

> > These comics (or comic strips) are very interesting.

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comic)

Answer (score 3):

*Comic*, singular, may designate either a 'strip', an integrated series of panels, published on a single occasion:

> today's comic = *the strip published today*
>
> the previous comic = *the last strip published before the current one*

or a work, a sequence of strips published under a single title:

> David Willis' newest comic 'Dumbing of Age'

*Comics* is the plural of *comic* in either sense, so it may designate either a set of strips

> today's comics = *the strips published today, typically the page of strips in a newspaper*
>
> last week's 'Dumbing of Age' comics = *the strips published last week under the title 'Dumbing of Age'*

or a set of works

> I regularly follow about a dozen comics.

Comment: Thank you, StoneyB. Is there any special word denoting one drawing of a comic?

Comment: @Yulia Each drawing is a 'panel'.